# Memory error when trying to plot a matrix with matplotlib

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib, similarity

I have a square matrix:

```
print(len(similarity_matrix)) #display 26003
```

I'm trying to plot a matrix like:

[image]

so I used matplolib:

```
plt.matshow(similarity_matrix)
plot.show()
```

But I have a memory error. How can I display my matrix?

Comment: There's no `mathshow` that I know of, only `matshow`. Don't print the `len`: print `similarity_matrix.shape`. But 26000^2 is indeed a lot of numbers. You can try `imshow` and `pcolormesh` as well, I don't know their respective memory needs.

Comment: I edit my mistake about mathshow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure produced by a 10000 by 10000 matrix takes 2.6 GB of memory. Suppose this scales linearly with the number of points, a 26000 by 26000 matrix would take 17 GB of memory. (I haven't tested because I only have 16 GB available)

Do you have more than 17 GB of memory available?

Another aspect may be that a usual screen has something like 2 million pixels. So it does make little sense wanting to display 670 million pixels on it.

Comment: No, how can I display it then?

Comment: Is this a joke? Buy a supercomputer maybe?

Comment: I was speaking about some method to reduce the size of the similarity matrix.

Comment: Downsampling, interpolation, averaging.. You need to know yourself what you want to show.